# What is the correct usage of "std::reduce"

Tags: c++

The following code compiles on MSVC but it fails on GCC. It seems GCC requires the type of the dereferenced iterator and `init` to be the same, even though there is no such requirement according to [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce). Note that if I replace `std::reduce()` with `std::accumulate()` then it works.

```
std::random_device e;
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, 10);
const int n = 10;
std::vector<int> v(n);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&]() {return dist(e); });
const auto result = std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end(), std::make_pair(0, 0),
    [](std::pair<int,int> sum,int n) {
        if (n % 2 == 1) sum.first += n;
        else sum.second += n;
        return sum;
    });
```

Comment: `gcc requires the type of the dereferenced iterator` from the doc you linked `binary FunctionObject that will be applied in unspecified order to the result of dereferencing the input iterators`

Comment: @KamilCuk OP expects that to be `n`.

Comment: cppreference has right on the reduce page *T must meet the requirements of MoveConstructible. and binary_op(init, *first), binary_op(*first, init), binary_op(init, init), and binary_op(*first, *first) must be convertible to T.*  Your operator can't work with `binary_op(*first, *first) `

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Only in one order. You're abusing `reduce`. Use a loop instead.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Maybe you thought I was OP? I'm trying to illustrate why OP thinks their code is okay.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Indeed :)

Comment: @NathanOliver yeah my bad i stopped reading after binary_op(init,*first). I guess what threw off is that i tried it with MSVC first and it worked so i assumed reduce() must have the same usage as accumulate. I wonder why the extra restriction, possibility of parallelization maybe?

Comment: @HikmatFarhat That is exactly why.  `reduce` was made to be able to split up the problem however it wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [[reduce]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/reduce#5)

> Mandates: All of
>
> - binary_­op(init, *first),
> - binary_­op(*first, init),
> - binary_­op(init, init), and
> - binary_­op(*first, *first)
>
> are convertible to T.

You lambda can't work for `binary_­op(*first, *first)` so gcc is correct in rejecting it.

Comment: The meaning of this code is clear: add all the odds into one element and add all the evens into the other. This can be implemented with `reduce` in a way that can take advantage of any optimization over `accumulate`. This answer would be better if it showed how to do that. Basically: overload `operator()` (perhaps by using cppreference's [`overloaded`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) helper). `op(n, pair(x, y)) = op(pair(x, y), n)` is as given, with extra cases `op(n, m) = op(n, m % 2 ? pair(m, 0) : pair(0, m))`, and `op(pair(x, y), pair(u, v)) = pair(x + u, y + v)`.