# std::reduce with a lambda returning a pair

Tags: c++, lambda, stl, reduce, variant

@HTNW noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62313504/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-stdreduce) that op's code use std::reduce if the provided lambda was defined with more overloads. Can someone please provide an example implementing this idea?

I am in a virtually identical situation and would like to take advantage of std::reduce's parallel policies instead of std::accumulate.

I attempted to create 4 versions of my function with each required argument types, but I do not see how to pass all 4 of these to std::reduce. I also tried giving std::visit 4 lambdas but this also did not compile.

For example, I'm not sure how to make the following code compile:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

#define N 100
#define seed 1

auto baz(std::pair<double,double> se, double vi){
  se.first  += vi;
  se.second *= 1+vi;
  return se;
}

auto baz(double vi, std::pair<double,double> se){
  return baz(se, vi);
}

auto baz(double vj, double vi){
  return std::pair(vi+vj,1.0);
}

auto baz(std::pair<double,double> se1, std::pair<double,double> se2){
  se1.first += se2.first;
  se1.second *= se2.second;
  return se1;
}

int main(){
  std::mt19937 rng(seed);
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0,1);
  std::vector<double> v(N);

  std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, v.begin(), v.end(), [&dist,&rng](double& c){ c = dist(rng); });

  for(auto x : v)
    std::cout << x << ", ";
  std::cout << "\n";

  // working accumulate code
  auto foo = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::pair(0.0,1.0), 
      [](std::pair<double,double> se, double vi){
        se.first  += vi;
        se.second *= 1+vi;
        return se;
      });
  std::cout << foo.first << " " << foo.second << "\n";

  auto bar = std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end(), std::pair(0.0,1.0), baz)
  std::cout << bar.first << " " << bar.second << "\n";

}
```

Comment: Please show more details - your attempts.

Comment: It'd be great if your question was more self-contained.

Comment: [Wrap it in a lambda](https://godbolt.org/z/dW7vh76sE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build an object that can be called with all 4 specified signatures. There are various ways to do this, but a simple technique is to use a polymorphic lambda:

```
[](auto x, auto y) { return baz(x, y); }
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/8Gff4bbof).